# Elliptic orbits and why sun located at focal point acts like at the center of the ellipse?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity

In the book "Classical Mechanics Point particles and relativity by Greiner"

We calculate Forces in the motion on an ellipse as follows

we first parametrizate the ellipse $$\vec r(t)=<a\cos(\omega t),b\sin(\omega t)>$$and take second derivative and found $$\vec F=m\vec a(t)=-m\omega^2 \vec r(t)$$

Which points the center of the ellipse

But then he follows "The planets also move around the sun along elliptic orbits. The sun as the center of attraction located in one of the focal points of the ellipse..."

with formula $$\vec F_G=-\gamma \dfrac{mM}{r^2}\dfrac{\vec r}{r}$$

Question: If the force required to hold the particle in elliptic orbit points center and the sun is at the focal point so what is the extra force which make the logic complete?

Comment: I mean, conservation of angular momentum is sufficient and neccessary for the radius vector should point parallel or anti parallel to the central force in this case Sun's gravitational force, so according to this sun must be at the center not at the focal??

Comment: The parameter t you used to parameterize the ellipse is not the time, that is not how a planet moves. And if the sun is in the focus, why the formula for F_G points to the center?

Comment: Okey let me sum my problem up. 
1) Parametrization is irrelevant because it is shown that if there is a force that hold the particle on the ellipse it must points to the center of the ellipse.
2) We know that Newton's formula F_G is written between two particles in this example Sun and Earth so the "$\vec r$" must be from Earth to the Sun.
3)Acording to these infos If we assume Sun is at a focal. Then we should conculude either this is an circle, not an ellipse, or there is a some additional force from sun to the center of the ellipse to satisfy the above theory. Otherwise it is contradicto

Comment: Notice that the v you obtain from your parametrization does not agree with the v from an orbit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit#Velocity

Comment: parametrization is relevant, because then you assume that the parameter is t! which is not. Plus the sun is not at the center, so why does the force point to it? it is inconsistent.

Comment: what is the page or chapter of the book where it shows that?

Comment: Actually the force you found is proportional to r, that is what you need for  the motion to be an ellipse with a central force, but gravity is proportional to 1/r^2

Comment: Kepler's conclusion was so remarkable for his time. First you have to translate from little white dots moving in 2D on the sky to actual motions in a 3D universe - that's no mean feat. Then why an ellipse? - an egg-shape seems much more likely to me.  Then wouldn't you expect the sun to be at the center of the ellipse? And how come the period doesn't depend on how wide the ellipse is?  And why is the orbit stationary in space?  This all seems a bit too weird to be true.  Of course, then Newton comes along later with his 1/r^2 and it all seems obvious.  But Kepler is one of my heroes. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That parametrization of the elipse corresponds to a body held by a linear elastic device to a point. That is the meaning of $F⃗ = −m\omega^2 r(t)$

If a or b is zero, it is a simple harmonic motion. But gravitational force is proportional to $\frac{1}{r^2}$, and is not described by that parametrization.